# How to declare generic ArrayList outside of static recursive method?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am trying to create a method that will recursively reverse an `ArrayList` of generics, and am running into issues with the declaration of my `reversedList` array (see line 4 of code below).

As the code stands, I receive the error:

> cannot find symbol Class: E

The only way I have found to stop the error is by declaring `reversedList` inside the method, but then it will reset every time it recurses.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListRecursive<E>{

   public static List<E> reversedList= new ArrayList<E>();

   public static  <E>  void reverse(ArrayList<E> inputList){

      E firstitem = null;
      if (inputList.size() == 0 ) {
         return;
      } 
      else {
         firstitem = inputList.get(0);
         inputList.remove(0);
      }
      reverse(inputList);
      reversedList.add( firstitem );
   }
```

Below is the main method, which creates an ArrayList of commmand line arguments and attempts to reverse it using the method above.

```
 public static void main(String args[]){


      ArrayList<String> argList = new ArrayList<>();
      ArrayList<Double> numericArgs = new ArrayList<>();
      for (String s : args) {
         argList.add(s);
         try {
            numericArgs.add(Double.parseDouble(s));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "is not numeric...skipping");
         }
      }
      System.out.print("Command line arguments before reversal: ");
      for (int i=0; i<argList.size(); i++)
         System.out.print(argList.get(i)+ " ");
      System.out.println();

      reverse(argList);

      System.out.print("Command line arguments afterreversal: ");

      for (int i=0; i<argList.size(); i++)
         System.out.print(argList.get(i)+ " ");
      System.out.println();
   }
```

Comment: Why are you declaring an `<E>` type on `reverse()` instead of using `<E>` as defined for the whole class?  (i.e. why are you making your method static?)

Comment: Use print statements in your code  and print values that you put in the list this will give you some heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that you.

1. Wanted to do it recursively
2. Didn't want to destroy the original list.
3. And didn't want to allocate the new List external to the method.

You can do the following:

```java
   public static <E> List<E> reverse(List<E> inputList) {
      List<E> ret = new ArrayList<>();
      E o = inputList.remove(0);
      if (inputList.size() > 0) {
         ret = reverse(inputList);
      }
      // at this point they will be on the stack in reverse order.

      // so add them to the stack in that order.
      ret.add(o);
      // return the orginal list to its initial state by inserting them at the beginning.
      inputList.add(0, o);
      return ret;
   }
```

Calling with this.

```java
      List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
      System.out.println(reverse(ints));
      System.out.println(ints);
```

Produces this output.

> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] 
>     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

A non-recursive solution would be, of course, trivial.

Note:  The passed List **must** support `List.remove()` and be `mutable` for this to work.  If you declare your list using `List.of()` or `Arrays.asList()` you must pass your list as an argument to the `ArrayList<>()` constructor.

Comment: Such a nice answer and downvoted! And that too without a comment! I upvote for it.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, if it's a utility method, why store the parameter, if not, then why is it static. You also don't need multiple instances, as method parameters in java are pass-by-reference. More importantly, recursive means your list will be limited to your call stack limit.

[Try It Online](https://ideone.com/t6Lxvj)

```
public static <E> void reverse(List<E> list) {
  for (int i=0;i<list.size()/2;i++) {
      E temp = list.get(i);
      list.set(i, list.get(list.size()-i-1));
      list.set(list.size()-i-1, temp);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, and while this solved my original issue, now I am running into issues in my main() where the given arraylist of command line arguments (strings) cannot be converted to my arraylist of E

Comment: @NorthernMcCullough check the link

Comment: @NorthernMcCullough if my solution helped, you can upvote it

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for it to show publicly as I have less than 15